# Create new default object for custom PropertyDrawer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

When you create new class and mark it as `[System.Serializable]` your inspector will create and show its default object for property of new class' type in your MonoBehaviour component.

When creating custom PropertyDrawer though you need to create this default object on your own and put its reference into SerializedProperty.objectReferenceValue (as far as I understand).

But this field is of type UnityEngine.Object and my new class cant be assigned there. How to overcome it? Inheriting your class from UnityEngine.Object doesnt help as SerializedProperty.objectReferenceValue is still null, even after assigning in there the newly created object (which is actually of the same type – UnityEngine.Object).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly, taken from [the Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html):

```
using UnityEngine;

public enum IngredientUnit { Spoon, Cup, Bowl, Piece }

// Custom serializable class
[Serializable]
public class Ingredient
{
    public string name;
    public int amount = 1;
    public IngredientUnit unit;
}

public class Recipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Ingredient potionResult;
    public Ingredient[] potionIngredients;
}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Ingredient))]
public class IngredientDrawerUIE : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override VisualElement CreatePropertyGUI(SerializedProperty property)
    {
        // Create property container element.
        var container = new VisualElement();

        // Create property fields.
        var amountField = new PropertyField(property.FindPropertyRelative("amount"));
        var unitField = new PropertyField(property.FindPropertyRelative("unit"));
        var nameField = new PropertyField(property.FindPropertyRelative("name"), "Fancy Name");

        // Add fields to the container.
        container.Add(amountField);
        container.Add(unitField);
        container.Add(nameField);

        return container;
    }
}
```

So when you view a GameObject with the `Recipe` component on it, Unity's inspector will show something like this:
[image]

So you do not need to inherit from anything, simply mark the class you want to create a property drawer as `Serializable`, and create a property drawer class for it (Make sure to place it in the `Editor` folder, or create a assembly definition file which targets the editor only if you are working with assembly definition files).

Comment: Youre right, I misunderstood that Untiy serializes [System.Serializable] objects on its own, and you dont really need to create them manaully and put into SerializedProperty.objectReferenceValue.